# How to prevent `$MANSECT` from being altered when using Vim as a manpager?

Tags: vim, man

Inside the file `~/.zshenv` I export this value for the `MANSECT` environment variable (the value is taken from `/etc/manpath.config`):

```
export MANSECT=1:n:l:8:3:2:3posix:3pm:3perl:5:4:9:6:7
```

This variable seems to control the order of the sections in which `$ man` searches for a manpage, when you don't specifiy one.

As an example, this command opens the `printf` manpage in the first section of the manual:

```
$ MANSECT=1:2:3 man printf
```

Because I didn't specify the section number I was interested in, and because the section `1` comes before the section `3` inside `$MANSECT`.

In contrast, this command opens the `printf` manpage in the third section of the manual:

```
MANSECT=3:2:1 man printf
```

Because the section `3` comes before the section `1` in `$MANSECT`.

---

Now, according to Vim's help (`:help manpager.vim`), Vim can be used as a manpager:

```
export MANPAGER="vim -M +MANPAGER -"
```

If I start Vim with the `$ vim` command, and ask for the value of `$MANSECT`, I get the original value (the one exported in the shell):

```
$ export MANSECT=1:2:3
$ export MANPAGER="vim -M +MANPAGER -"
$ vim
:echo $MANSECT
```

The last `:echo` correctly prints `1:2:3` on Vim's command line.

But if I start Vim with the `$ man` command:

```
$ export MANSECT=1:2:3
$ export MANPAGER="vim -M +MANPAGER -"
$ man man
:echo $MANSECT
```

The last `:echo` prints only `1` on Vim's command line, instead of `1:2:3`.

---

Some information about my machine:

- `vim --version`:      VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1  Included patches: 1-495
- `man --version`:      2.7.5
- Operating system:     Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
- Terminal emulator:    rxvt-unicode v9.22
- Terminal multiplexer: tmux 2.8
- `$TERM`:              tmux-256color
- Shell:                zsh 5.6.2-dev-0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

---

Is it possible to prevent `$MANSECT` from being altered when using Vim as a manpager?

The reason I ask this question is because the [Neovim man plugin](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/plugin/man.vim) suffers from an issue where you can't open a manpage outside the first section of the manual if you have started Neovim as a manpager:

```
$ export MANSECT=1:n:l:8:3:2:3posix:3pm:3perl:5:4:9:6:7
$ export MANPAGER='nvim +Man!'
$ man man
:Man mount
```

The last command raises the following error:

```
man.vim: command error (11) man -w mount: No manual entry for mount
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

This is due to `$MANSECT` having been truncated to the first section number (`1`), and the manpage for `$ mount` is in the section `8`.

Comment: Try:
declare -r MANSECT=1:n:l:8:3:2:3posix:3pm:3perl:5:4:9:6:7
export MANSECT

Comment: @pacmanwa Thank you very much for the comment. I just tried the command, but unfortunately, the value of `$MANSECT` is still truncated inside (Neo)Vim.